# SUPEE-5344 Patching problems magento 1.7.x.x

Tags: magento-1.7, patches

I have uploaded the patch to my root Magento folder but I get the following error

```
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php.rej
```

I see this question has been asked and I tried to upload the patched file as described on:

http://magentary.com/kb/apply-supee-5344-and-supee-1533-without-ssh/

but this causes my site to crash.

Comment: What was the error message when applying the patch? Did you maybe do any custom modifications to lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php?
Check the content of the lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php.rej file.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I didn't make any modifications to it and no lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php.rej was created. I have looked in the magento directory on the server

Comment: You don't have to make any modifications to the file, just transfer it to the live server in a manner that doesn't properly translate line endings. PHP is line ending agnostic, Linux shell utilities aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer this https://www.milople.com/blogs/ecommerce/applying-magento-security-patch.html

It works fine.

Comment: You should update your answer and add the most important information from the website here. Just in case the link turns invalid some time.

Answer (score 1):

Patch is used for lots of things other than Magento, here's what causes hunk failures => [Error patching Magento, hunk failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703404/error-patching-magento-1-7-1-hunk-1-failed-at) => [Magento patch installation errors](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64221/5344-security-patch-installation-error-in-magento)

Often, if you download the Magento installation archive for the exact version you're running from the [Magento Downloads Page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download) on the Release Archive tab, extract the file and replace the server file that's giving you the issue, the patch will complete properly.

You can also run the file through `dos2unix` to correct the line endings as the line endings may be CRLF instead of the LF that Linux and its utilities expects.